# Django max based on foreign key queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, annotate

I would like to annotate a queryset based on a foreign key, i.e.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class B(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

I would like to annotate the `B` queryset with `Max`, but each `Max` being filtered to the `a` foreign key.

I have a feeling I would have to filter out the foreign key I wanted, and then annotate.

```
qs = B.objects.filter(a=some_specific_instance_of_A).annotate(max_value=Max('value'))
```

But would like to do something like

```
qs = B.objects.annotate(max_value=Max('value'), key='a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values) clause to group prior to annotating.

```
qs = B.objects.values('a').annotate(max_value=Max('value'))
```